# Which is more efficient performance-wise price mysql table for size/product or price in csv format in a text column

Tags: php, mysql

Consider an example of a fabric store where customers can order any combination of sizes and the prices differ every 10cm. e.g. 100x100 = $100 110x100 = $110  110x110 = $140 ..etc (there is no pattern, price not per XXcm)

Would it be better to store a table of prices in a csv format in products table as a text column for each product and then php code interprets the table based on the size selected?   or store them in a separate mysql table one for entry for each product and size combination?

My concern for text column is it increases the product table size greatly, but not sure if I make the prices as separate table would be much better.

Comment: Obviously storing the prices in a separate table is the best thing to do if you are using a relational database.

Comment: Text columns will give you a large number of unnecessary hassles down the line. A junction table would be better off.

Comment: Does a larger row size affect mysql performance?  say if we have a table of 1mb  vs a table of 10mb due to the size of a text column that won't be searched via sql query.

Answer (score 1):

Storing the prices in a separate table sounds like the most relationally sound option, if there is really no algorithm by which you can find out the price, like say by square cm for example.

An extra table gives you much better flexibility if you need to bulk change things. Also you can query the different sizes easily and compare them.

I would keep the width and height and price in separate columns in that table.

An `INNER JOIN` is also really not that expensive for a database if you use the right indexes/keys on the tables. So the main use - query a fabric for all available prices is comparatively cheap.